# Book about small town, deadly virus, and US Army clean-up team killing everyone

Tags: story-identification, novel, virus

This is a sci-fi book from around the 1980s.

Local police in some town in the US search a crashed cargo truck with a dead driver.  After opening many safety boxes there is an egg (infected with the virus) and soon everyone gets sick, especially males in military age. The exception is pregnant females, one being local sheriff's daughter.

There is a US army clean-up team trying to kill everyone. The town resists, the resistance facilitated by the good sheriff and a Vietnam veteran/former helicopter pilot who lives in the hippie community. As the army fails to contain and kill everyone, they ultimately decide to crash a huge air tanker to wipe the whole town out.

The virus is like flu but then turns more deadly as it causes fast cancer whenever an infected is exposed to any plastic, exhaust fumes, rubber or synthetic materials.

Comment: Sounds like it was inspired by the andromeda strain

Comment: Something by Dean Koontz?

Comment: If it weren’t for some of these elements, this sounds a lot like the opening to The Stand

Answer (score 9):

It’s *[Jericho Falls](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Jericho_Falls/Y9xLo_cg7JEC?hl=en)* from Christopher Hyde, first published 1986.

> When a freak accident causes a truck to overturn in Jericho Falls, a lethal virus is unleashed, and only Sheriff Jack Slater and a handful of people with a strange immunity can stop it

Indeed, text from [the archive.org copy of the book](https://archive.org/details/jerichofalls00chri/mode/2up?view=theater&q=egg) confirms the egg.

> He stuck the flashlight under his arm and tugged at the top of the bottle, unscrewing it. Inside the bottle there was another insert of foam rubber and what appeared to be a second metal container, about the size of an old-fashioned seven-ounce Coke bottle. Dor- chester made a small sound of annoyance. It was like those Ukrainian dolls that kept on getting smaller. He slid the smaller flask out and looked at it. Another string of numbers and a thin seam in the metal about a third of the way down. Putting the two pieces of the big container on the floor of the van, he wrapped his hands around the smaller flask and twisted. It opened easily, revealing its contents. There, nestled snugly in a bed of ordinary cotton wool, was an egg. Grade A Large by the look of it.
>
> "Christ on a fucking crutch!" snorted Dorchester, disgusted. All that effort for a goddamn egg. Using two fingers, he picked the egg up from its bed of cotton. The guy up front was a lunatic, running around the countryside with crates of eggs all bundled up like they were the fucking Crown Jewels of England. Furious, the policeman threw the fragile orb against the inside wall of the van. The shell broke wetly and a gluey mixture of yolk and white splattered everywhere. Dorchester wrinkled his nose and then sneezed hard. On top of everything else, it smelled like the things were rotten.
>
> "Shit!" Sneezing again, Dorchester backed out of the van, eyes watering at the foul odor. What a goddamn joke! Not only was the night screwed beyond redemption, but now his uniform smelled of rotten egg. He dropped down to the ground and slammed the door shut. His eyes were still watering from the stink, and his nose was running. He wiped it on the sleeve of his jacket and backed away from the van.

And indeed, pregnant women seem to be immune:

> "It's not influenza," Payne said. "It's a secondary infection brought about by exposure to a mutated bacteria. It seems to affect people between the ages of fourteen and fifty-five, men and women. For some reason, pregnant women don't get it, and neither do diabetics. By my estimation, at least two-thirds of the citizens of this town who fall within that age group have contracted the disease to a greater or lesser extent."